Deriving Fourier Transform from its inverse.
While there are many answers on stack exchange developing intuition for the Fourier Transform, the easiest way I could wrap my head conceptually around the practical result of the transform as a sinusoidal decomposition was to begin with the equation of the inverse transform:
$$f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(\omega)e^{i\omega t}d\omega$$
Here, we see that f(t) is the sum of particular sinusoidal functions of all possible frequencies. Now from this equation, how can we analytically derive the following definition of the Fourier transform.
$$g(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt$$
Or in other words, how can we solve for g from the first equation?
Edit:
With the helpful comment by @JohnBarber about the delta function, I came up with the following solution; is it valid? I am particularly concerned about the switching of the differentials? $$f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(\omega)e^{i\omega t}d\omega\\ \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{f(t)}{2\pi}e^{-i\omega 't}dt = \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-i\omega 't}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(\omega)e^{i\omega t}d\omega dt \\\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f(t)e^{-i\omega 't}dt = \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(\omega)e^{i(\omega-\omega ') t}d\omega dt \\ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f(t)e^{-i\omega 't}dt = \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(\omega)e^{i(\omega-\omega ') t}dtd\omega \\ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f(t)e^{-i\omega 't}dt = \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }g(\omega)\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i(\omega-\omega ') t}dtd\omega \\ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f(t)e^{-i\omega 't}dt = \int_{-\infty }^{\infty }g(\omega)\delta (\omega - \omega ')d\omega \\  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f(t)e^{-i\omega 't}dt = g(\omega ')$$

Are you familiar with the Dirac delta function?

@JohnBarber Yes, informally from physics classes but never learned them in a math class

The equation for $g(\omega)$ can be derived by multiplying your first equation by $\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-i\omega't}$ and integrating from $t = -\infty$ to $t = +\infty$. Then use the definition of the delta function as an integral: $\delta(\omega-\omega') = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i(\omega-\omega')t}dt$

This is an entire subject independent of $\delta$.

It is easy to prove this for the discrete Fourier transform (basically the same argument you gave).  Now wave your hands, say Riemann integrals, and take limits.
